# Pausar y Continuar reproducción de audio de un AVPlayer Swift Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Estoy reproduciendo un audio mp3 desde una url. Esto lo realizo de la siguiente forma:

```
var player : AVPlayer?


@IBAction func btn_reproducir(_ sender: Any) {
     if self.player != nil {
        //ya esta reproduciendo, pausamos
        print("===== Entramos a pausa")
        self.player?.pause()

        self.btnAudio.image = UIImage(systemName: "play.fill")

    }else{
        //Iniciar reproduccion
        print("===== Entramos a play")
        guard let url = URL.init(string: "http://www.pagina.com/mi.mp3") else { return }
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem.init(url: url)
        self.player = AVPlayer.init(playerItem: playerItem)
        self.player?.play()

        self.btnAudio.image = UIImage(systemName: "pause.fill")


    }


}
```

El audio reproduce bien, después lo pausa bien.

Necesito validar el "player" para PAUSAR o CONTINUAR según el estado de la reproducción.

Como se valida el estado del player para PAUSAR cuando este en reproducción y REANUDAR cuando esté pausado ?

Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente encontre esta solucion. no se si es la manera correcta de validarlo pero trabaja para mi en Xcode 11.5, iOS 13

```
    @IBAction func btn_reproducir(_ sender: Any) {
    let strUrl = "http://www.pagina.com/mi.mp3"

    if self.player?.timeControlStatus == AVPlayer.TimeControlStatus.playing{
        //print("===== PAUSA")
        self.player?.pause()
        self.btnAudio.image = UIImage(systemName: "play.fill")

    }else{
        //print("===== INICIO - CONTINUAR")
        if self.player != nil {
            //print("CONTINUAR")
            self.player?.play()
            self.btnAudio.image = UIImage(systemName: "pause.fill")

        }else{
            //print("INICIAR")
            guard let url = URL.init(string: strUrl) else { return }
            let playerItem = AVPlayerItem.init(url: url)
            self.player = AVPlayer.init(playerItem: playerItem)
            self.player?.play()
            self.btnAudio.image = UIImage(systemName: "pause.fill")
        }


    }

}
```